# How could the new MacBook Pro connect to a external display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have a DELL UP 2516Dt and I used to connect it to my old MacBook Pro with a HDMI.

But for the new MBP. I tried the so-called "Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3" but it's not working (I found a lot of negative reviews at Apple Store).

I think this picture below describes quite well my confusion.

[image]

What should I try now to get them connected?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from reading the manual for the Dell monitor to see what video inputs it has and the video support tech spec's for the MBP, so as to determine what adapter and or cable you'll need, also have a look at: [MacBook Pro Thunderbolt 3 adapter guide: How to connect an iPhone, display, hard drive, and more](http://www.macworld.com/article/3136583/macbook-accessories/macbook-pro-thunderbolt-3-adapter-guide-how-to-connect-an-iphone-display-hard-drive-and-more.html)

Comment: This [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259551/119271) addresses your ***exact*** question.  I am not quite sure if this should be flagged as a dupe because though the linked question is about two monitors and yours is about a single monitor, the basic premise and the answers are the same.

Comment: @Allan, Are you aware it says, at the link you've provided for the cable in your answer, "Currently unavailable. We don't know when or if this item will be back in stock."?

Comment: @user3439894 - I wasn't aware; thanks! That Pluggable is the exact cable I purchased for a relative and it worked flawlessly - I'm surprised you can't get them.  Anyway...give this one a shot - I haven't tested it, but it's an [Anker](https://goo.gl/Bx8Y6b) and they have an 18 month warranty.  I've already added it to my list for the next time.

Answer (score 2):

This adapter should work:
http://www.apple.com/de/shop/product/MJ1K2ZM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter

It's a bit bulky but it should do the trick if it's actually HDMI, the picture though looks not like HDMI
[image: HDMI]
<sub>(source: [cctv.help](http://cctv.help/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/HDMI-Cable.jpg))</sub>

Edit: It looks like Displayport and then you need this one:
[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-Compatible/dp/B01J6DT070/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1484139767&sr=8-3&keywords=thunderbolt+3+to+displayport](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J6DT070)