# USB-C to DP cable yields only 30Hz

Tags: display, usb, displayport, resolution

I am using a MacBook Pro 2017 (two USB-C ports, running Ventura) and want to connect it to a Dell P2415Q monitor. For that reason, I have bought [this USB-C to DP-cable](https://www.amazon.de/AmazonBasics-Bi-Directional-USB-C-DisplayPort-Cable/dp/B081VK7Q94). The monitor shows 4K @ 30Hz only, and I am unable to get 60Hz out of it. I am certain that the monitor supports 4K @ 60Hz over DP, because I have successfully used that with my last MacBook Pro. That the Computer supports it is out of question, and Amazon claims that the cable supports 4K @ 60Hz, too. Where (and how) can I find the problem?

Comment: I’m not a fan of Amazon Basics; it’s cheap stuff they slap their name on to sell toms of.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259551/119271) for a rec.  11€ is quite low for a cable.  A good one costs nearly twice that.

Comment: That Amazon page says this cable supports 2k@60, not 4k@60.

Comment: @MarcWilson no, 3840 x 2160 is 4K. And the page says this resolution is supported at 60Hz.

Comment: Which version of macOS was your last MacBook Pro using?

Comment: @DavidAnderson macOS Monterey, iirc. The last MacBook Pro (2015) was connected with a mini-DP to DP-cable.

Comment: @Bubaya I am well aware of what 4k is.  But the linked page only says 2k@60, it doesn't mention any refresh rate for 4k.

Comment: @MarcWilson You mean, *unterstützt Auflösungen bis 4K (3840 x 2160 Pixel); klares Bild und Audio mit einer schnellen Bildwiederholrate von 60 Hz* is supposed to mean either 4K *or* 60 Hz? Wow. If that's what they meant, I'm impressed by their boldness.

Comment: @MarcWilson The comments on A. confirm that it does 4K@60Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not the cable, but the MST (daisy chaining) screen setting. After switching MST on and off repeatedly on the screen (eventually, off), it worked.